# ffmepg - How to reduce size of video with many still images

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have many videos that contain mostly still images with almost no motion.
Only in some sequences there are animated scences with much motion.

Now I want to reduce their filesize, but ffmpeg with crf or a given bitrate doesn't seem to be the best way. Is there any option to let ffmpeg automatically use higher bitrates in scenes with motion and a bitrate of almost 0 in most scenes (like a buffer or so)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's sort of what CRF is supposed to do; CRF is supposed to maintain constant perceptual quality. Alternatively, if you need to target a particular file size, you can use two-pass mode (with `-pass` and `-passlogfile`), where the first pass should discover which scenes need bits, and the second pass will allocate the bits as best it can.

Some codes have tuning options for different video types — for example, if you're encoding to H.264, try tune stillimage or animation. (And of course, try changing codecs if that's an option. Or depending on image type, enable 10bit for H.264, again if that's an option.)

It might be worth fiddling with scene change detection and keyframes. A lot of times you want one with your still image; worst possible encode is often to initially display the still image full of artifacts and have a keyframe in the middle where it suddenly becomes clear... There are a bunch of options around this; the brute-force one is `-force_key_frames`.

If nothing else works, you can use `-rc_override` to manually set the quantizer/quality factor on a per-frame basis. In particular, if you set the rest of the options to make your still frames acceptable, you might use it to fix the animated portions. But this is a last resort, as it's a lot of work!

Depending on what the still frames are, though, they can take a lot of bits. Video encoding is in large part figuring out how to express motion in as few bits as possible; complicated still frames just take a lot of bits, especially since the viewer has plenty of time to notice any artifacts.

I'm not sure if you're aware of Stack Exchange's [video production site](https://video.stackexchange.com/); that could be a good place to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you!
How do I use the two-pass mode?

Comment: @shlomat23 I added in the two options to enable it — the main one is `-pass`. You do your first pass with `-pass 1`. Then you do the second pass with `-pass 2`.